# how to access type list of tuple values of module [NICs] output into another module[VM] in azure terraform

Tags: module, terraform, azure-cloud-services

| var.nic1-id is tuple with 2 elements

Inappropriate value for attribute "network_interface_ids": element 0: string
required.
Please help me in this issue!

Comment: output:

output "nic1-id" {
  value = azurerm_network_interface.NIC1.*.id
}

main.tf of  VM:


network_interface_ids = [var.nic1-id]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `var.nic1-id` is a list, then you would do:

```
network_interface_ids = var.nic1-id
```

Otherwise, you are creating a list of lists, which results in your error.

Comment: added above value in my code getting error again

Error: Incorrect attribute value type

  on .terraform\modules\fpm\main.tf line 27, in resource "azurerm_linux_virtual_machine" "main1":
  27:   network_interface_ids = var.nic1-id
    |----------------
    | var.nic1-id is tuple with 2 elements

Inappropriate value for attribute "network_interface_ids": element 0: string
required.

Comment: @Harik It would be better if you updated question and provided information on what exactly `var.nic1-id` is? What is `azurerm_network_interface.NIC1`? How and where do you use ` network_interface_ids`?

Comment: im creating separate module called nic and var.nic1-id  is output value and using this i'm to attach  the VM  module

Comment: @Harik Can you provide code example for that? You can update your question to add it.

Comment: The above answer is working fine for me !.Thank you so Mr. Marcin

Comment: getting another issue~

Comment: I'm plan to add other nic values to linux VM .
network_interface_ids =[ var.nic1-id , var.nic2-id]

getting below error:

var.nic1-id is tuple with 2 elements
    | var.nic2-id is tuple with 2 elements

Comment: @Harik If you can, new question with new details would be advised to make.

Comment: sure Thank I will create new question